# Laravel/Vue: SSR function not available in <script setup>

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, vite, server-side-rendering, laravel-breeze

It seems `route()` cannot be used in `<script>` and only in `<template>` when running Server-Side-Rendering.

So the question is: How to use the `route()` in the script when in SSR?

## Steps to repreduce the error

### 1. Installation

Install new Laravel project

```bash
composer create-project laravel/laravel ssrtest
```

Go to the directory

```bash
cd ssrtest
```

Require laravel/breeze package

```bash
$ composer require laravel/breeze --dev
```

Install breeze using vue with ssr

```bash
php artisan breeze:install vue --ssr
```

### 2. Start server

Run server

```bash
php artisan serve
```

Open a new terminal/console in the same directory and start de node ssr command

```bash
php artisan inertia:start-ssr
```

**Now you are running in SSR-mode where the routes are working .**

You can now navigate to /login and back through the function `route('login')` in de Link-component in `resources/js/Pages/Welcome.vue` on line 37.

### 3. Creating the error

1. First stop the ssr-node command. In the terminal `Ctrl+C`.
2. Add the following link in de script-section of Welcome.vue

```js
const testLink = route("login");
```

3. Run the build again and start the ssr

```bash
npm run build && php artisan inertia:start-ssr
```

4. Reload page in the browser
5. See terminal for error

   Short version:

   ```
   [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function ...

   ReferenceError: route is not defined
   ```

Comment: How about passing the route info from the server to the client-side script? like include the route info in a meta-tag within the HTML document, then access this data in your client-side script. Like `<meta name="route-data" content="{{ json_encode(['login' => route('login')]) }}">`

Comment: I just followed your reproduction steps, and I don't get the error you're mentioning.

Comment: Errors are appearing in the terminal where the `php artisan inertia:start-ssr` is running. Page seems running fine.

Comment: To fetch data from meta tags the `document` needs to be used. This is not available in ssr.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* i found *a* solution.

It might not be the best...so...if someone has a better idea: i'm all ears.

```
import { Head, Link, usePage } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import { useRoute } from "/vendor/tightenco/ziggy";

const route = useRoute(usePage().props.ziggy);
const testlink = route("login");
```

This way you can use `route()` in `<script setup>` and `<template>`